# What type of drill bit is best for following a long pilot hole in wood?

Tags: drill-bits

My plan is to rout a 1/4" wide channel in 3/4" plywood cutout, then glue it facewise to a similar 1/2" plywood cutout, forming an internal 1/4" pilot hole lengthwise that is square in cross-section. That pilot hole will then be drilled out with a long 3/8" bit. Material is purebond birch plywood.

I need a bit that will track the center of the square pilot, keeping the resulting hole as centered to the pilot as possible. Would also be good if it could have good chip ejection, since the hole will be quite deep, perhaps 14" in places; I will have many such holes to drill, so if possible it would be preferred to not have to withdraw frequently while drilling. It will be a through-hole, so a clean exit is also preferred.

In summary, my requirements are:

- Cut a 14" deep hole
- 3/8" in diameter
- Will follow a 1/4" pilot hole of square-cross-section

My preferences are, in decreasing importance:

- Track center of pilot hole throughout entire depth
- Clean exit
- good chip ejection

Brad point?
Spur?
General-purpose-twist?
Tapered?
Any other type?
Are there any other considerations that I've overlooked?
Which drill bit is best for this purpose?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. We actually have a/some previous Q&As about drilling deep holes in wood, and I'm afraid the news is not good in terms of doing what you want in the way you want. Did you try searching for 15" bits already and if so what did you find? (Given you appear to have access to both ends of the 'pilot' you may actually only need an 8" bit however.) But *I think* your starting conditions are perfectly set up to do one of the standard workarounds, which is to route 2 halves of the needed hole & then bring the pieces together (lamp bases were often done this way in the past).

Comment: @Graphus is right about a core box router bit being the solution to all your problems, but if for whatever reason that isn’t going to work, then a standard twist drill (like a traditional metal bit) will follow your path better than anything else.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate, conventionally you're correct, but there are deep-hole bits with certain oddball tips that we don't normally see — modern fluted ([example](https://www.willyvanhoutte.com/image_cache/willyvanhoutte/A7000/7496/wv-hct160-2b-cat-8aacf7eadc892d0936fbb0c333f274f3-article-zoom-default.jpg)), wedge point and straight fluted — that may actually follow a pilot better. With a twist bit, at the required diameter and that length of travel, there's plenty of potential for wander, and the flexibility of any bit only 3.8" must be acknowledged.